# Google Analytics shows increase in visits for that day after the day has passes

Tags: google-analytics

I am having a problem with Google Analytics reporting.

For example, this morning I checked my 'Audience overview' and saw that I had gotten 50 visits  yesterday and today until that time in the morning I had gotten 20 visits.

Now in the evening I check, and it is showing that yesterday I got 90 visits and today I have gotten 25 visits.

What is going on? today's visit from 20 to 25 is not the problem. But how come yesterday's visits increased from 50 to 90 visits, after the day has passed? What is going on?

Did I get 50 or 90 visits?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lag in the reporting in Google Analytics. Typically a few hours but as much as a full day.

Comment: So I got 90 visits yesterday?

Comment: Are you sure you're not applying a segment or looking at some other view of the data?

Comment: No it is the same. I make sure I always of 'Visitors' selected and I don't choose any segment. But still the report from previous days fluctuates. First it shows a lower number, than a higher number and then a different lower number. This cannot be possible even if there is a lag.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of what you're seeing? I've never seen behavior like this in GA.